# In-App purchases not loading unless I install the app directly from Xcode - RevenueCat

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I recently started using `RevenueCat` for all of my InApp purchases; today my app was approved in the App Store so, I went ahead and downloaded it to try the new version directly from the App Store and I noticed that the In-App purchases are not loading. What is funny is that if I connect my phone to my computer and compile the app directly from Xcode it does show the In-App purchases.

So my question is, is there any setting in RevenueCat that we need to turn on when the app goes into production?

If such of setting does not exist, what would be a good way to troubleshoot the issue to determine where the problem is, if it's RevenueCat, the App Store or my code?

FYI - When I install the app directly from Xcode I can make purchases with a send-box account and everything functions as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any RevenueCat settings to update when your app goes live. This sounds like a propagation issues with the App Store if these are new products - sometimes they can take ~24hrs to be available in production to all users after being approved.

Unfortunately, doing nothing and waiting is probably the answer here. In the future if you can not show new products to users until >24hrs after they're approved it should prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Ah ok, Thank you for the clarification. I will wait then. Thanks

Comment: Can you send an email to support@revenuecat.com with details about your app? I'll look into it and update the answer if we discover anything new.

Comment: Oh, sure. What info do you need to access my account?

Comment: I just sent you an email, hopefully, I sent you the info you need to access my account. Please let me know if you find something wrong. Thanks a lot for your help.